# CURL: how to run a single curl command 100 times?

Tags: curl

I have the following curl command:
curl -i -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X POST -d @hundredencoded http:///aaa/bbb/message

For load testing, i need to run this command 100 times, how do i do it using CURL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a shell script, probably. Which platform?

Comment: you can try it for Loop he above code in shell Script

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could achieve it by using the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(eval echo {1..$1})
do 
  curl -i -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -X POST -d @hundredencoded http:///aaa/bbb/message &  
done
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this is the error when i run the run.sh.   gnome-terminal: command not found

Comment: @user2377310 what platform are you using ? is it not linux ?

Comment: I am running this on MAC terminal window.

Comment: Having a hard time understanding why pop one terminal per curl, or at all.  Just do it in the background: `curl [...] &` and add 'disown' after the `&` if you don't want the horde of jobs.

Comment: This has worked! thanks! :)                                          #!/bin/bash

 for i in $(eval echo {1..$1})
 do 

curl -i -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X POST -d @hundredencoded http:///aaa/bbb/message ;

done

Comment: @user2377310 put & at the end to make it background as jthill suggested . i edited that script too

Answer (score 10):

Although the question specify using curl for this task, I would highly recommend using ab for this.

ab (Apache Benchmark) is a tool build specifically for the case in question. It allows you to call a specific request multiple times and also define concurrency.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Your test would be:

```
ab -p post.txt -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -n 100 -c 1 http://aaa/bbb/message
```

or, even shorter:

```
ab -p post.txt -T text/plain -n 100 -c 1 http://aaa/bbb/message
```

Where the file `post.txt` holds the POST data.